# Disable double tap zoom in MKMapView (iOS 6)

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, mkmapview, ios6

in ios 5 i was able to disable the double tap zoom by just overriding it with a new double tap gesture. But it seems that the double tap gesture is no longer in the gesturerecognizer array that comes with the mkmapview.

```
NSArray *gestureRecognizers = [_mapView gestureRecognizers];
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in gestureRecognizers) {
    NSLog(@"%@", recognizer);
}
```

returns nothing in ios 6, where in ios 5 it would return 2 recognizers, one for single tap and one for double tap.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd look through the gesture recognizers of MKMapView's subviews. It's probably still there somewhere.

Of course, messing around with another view's GRs is slightly dubious and will likely break the next time Apple changes something about MKMapView...

**EDIT:** For the benefit of anyone else reading this, *please* check that it's a `UITapGestureRecognizer` and that `numberOfTapsRequired == 2` and `numberOfTouchesRequired == 1`.

Also, instead of disabling double-taps on the map entirely, consider adding a double-tap GR on the annotation and then do `[mapDoubleTapGR requireGestureRecognizerToFail:annotationDoubleTapGR]`. Again, hacky — don't blame me if it breaks on the next OS update!

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:
[_mapView.subviews[0] addGestureRecognizer:MyDoubleTapOverrider];

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to let the user do anything with the view? If not, it sufficient to set `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO`. If so, what specific interactions do you need to allow? Everything but double-tapping? Why disable that one interaction?

The more we know about your use case, the better the answers we can provide.

Comment: I want the user to be able to tap, not double-tap. In my app the user sometimes have to tap multipli times on one annotation, so i dont want the app to zoom. Thanks for helping out

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
    //INIT the MKMapView    
    -(id) init{
         ...
         [self getGesturesRecursive:mapView];
         ...
    }
```

And then let the recursive function loop through the subviews and find the GR:s.

```
    -(void)getGesturesRecursive:(UIView*)v{
         NSArray *gestureRecognizers = [v gestureRecognizers];
         for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in gestureRecognizers) {
             if ([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {                  
                [v removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
             }
        }

        for (UIView *v1 in v.subviews){
            [self getGesturesRecursive:v1];
        }
    }
```

This example removes all tap-GR:s. But I guess you can specify to remove whatever you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a long tap gesture instead, that works.