# iOS: Is it possible to add a triple tap gesture recognizer to a MKMapView?

Tags: ios, mkmapview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `MKMapView`, which zooms in when double tapped (default behavior). I want to add a triple tap gesture recognizer to the map view that zooms out again to a certain initial zoom level.
The problem is that the built-in double tap recognizer fires first. In order to delay this, one had to access the double tap recognizer in some way, but at least in iOS6 the `view` property `gestureRecognizers` does not contain the double tap recognizer of the map view.
So, is it possible to delay the double tap recognizer in some way in order to allow the triple tap recognizer to fire first?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable double tap zoom in MKMapView (iOS 6)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521017/disable-double-tap-zoom-in-mkmapview-ios-6)

Comment: The answer in the link cited relies on accessing the gestureRecognizers property of the map view, but this is apparently no longer possible in iOS6.

Comment: I understand, but I think that what this indicates is that Apple doesn't want you to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the instance method `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` in the `UIGestureRecognizer` class.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIGestureRecognizer/requireGestureRecognizerToFail:

> Creates a dependency relationship between the receiver and another gesture recognizer.

For example:

```
[doubleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tripleTap];
```

---

### Update

After goofing around with it for a bit, I've got it working like this (assuming you've got an `MKMapView` named `mapView`):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tripleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTripleTap:)];
tripleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 3;
[mapView.subviews[0] addGestureRecognizer:tripleTap];

UIView *tempMapView = mapView.subviews[0];
NSArray *mapGestures = tempMapView.gestureRecognizers;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tempMapDoubleTap = mapGestures[0];
[tempMapDoubleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tripleTap];
NSLog(@"%@", mapGestures);
```

Triple Tap Selector:

```
- (void)handleTripleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    NSLog(@"Triple Tap Detected..");
}
```

Now double-tapping still zooms the `MKMapView` and triple-tapping successfully executes `handleTripleTap` without zooming.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought about this also. The problem is that I don't know how to access the built-in double tap recognizer.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't realized that doing what was suggested in @matt's comment above had been disallowed by Apple.  Bummer!  I'm going to look into this a bit more, I'll post more if I find anything.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner, I've got it working now - see my updated post.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are great! It works. I would not have thought about this solution.

Comment: Glad I was more help this time than in your other question a couple months ago (UIButton backgrounds)!

Comment: Ah! This was you also! Thanks for pointing this out! I hope I can help you sometime also...